# Finding users' HOMEPATHs from a service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, user-accounts, local-system-account

In the process of writing a service I have

```
        //# Service Account Information
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```

in the installer for it.

I was having problems writing a log to

```
    static string USERS_HOME_DIR = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE") + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH");
```

since when the service was running (installed "as administrator") the event logger was reporting

> Service cannot be started. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents\Folder of Interest'

I need the HOMEPATHs of the users of the local_PC, any ideas how to get them?

**UPDATE**

Actually it would be better to just get the path for the currently logged on user, as their session and the service start. My sevice is not re-entrant but one user is better than none.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting logged-on username from a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238133/getting-logged-on-username-from-a-service)

Comment: @phresnel I'd rather iterate all users' homepaths than use unmanaged dll's.

Comment: I'm also happy for it to start once and only once when the first user logs in and to use their homepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly what you're looking for are the [special folder enumerations](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32384).

With something like:

```
String PersonalFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

If you want to run the service as the localsystem account there's a separate set of standards for storing the data. See [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accoun).

Comment: Yes, that's what I asked, though I'm not sure it is responsible for the non-starter error I get logged.

Comment: Understood - I've updated my answer, again, a little tenuous but I think I'm answering the question! :)

Comment: I'm liking this answer more and more after a stack trace in the Computer Management 'console' - if console is the right term?

Comment: I think I need an autorun.exe architecture.